# Django is form not showing up

Tags: django

my form is not showing up. Could someone please help me

media_form.html

```
{%  extends 'accounts/main.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="card card-body">

            <form action="" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{form}}
                
                <input type="submit" name="Submit">
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>


{% endblock %}
```

dashboard.html

```
{%  extends 'accounts/main.html' %}

{% block content %}

{%  include 'accounts/status.html' %}

<br>

<a class="btn btn-primary  btn-sm btn-block" href="{% url 'media_form' %}">Add Media</a>


    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h5>CONTINUE WATCHING</h5>
        <hr>
        <div class="card card-body">
            <table class="table table-sm">
                <tr>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Language</th>
                    <th>Rating</th>
                    <th>Type of Media</th>
                    <th>Genre</th>
                    <th>Review</th>
                    <th>Notes</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Update</th>
                    <th>Remove</th>
                </tr>

                {% for media in media_continue_watching %}
                    <tr>
                         <td>{{media.title}}</td>
                         <td>{{media.language}}</td>
                         <td>{{media.rating}}</td>
                         <td>{{media.type_of_media}}</td>
                         <td>{{media.genre}}</td>
                         <td>{{media.review}}</td>
                         <td>{{media.notes}}</td>
                         <td>{{media.date}}</td>
                         <td><a href="">Update</a></td>
                         <td><a href="">Delete</a></td>

                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
        
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h5>PLAN TO WATCH</h5>
        <hr>
        <div class="card card-body">
            <table class="table table-sm">
                <tr>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Language</th>
                    <th>Rating</th>
                    <th>Type of Media</th>
                    <th>Genre</th>
                    <th>Review</th>
                    <th>Notes</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Update</th>
                    <th>Remove</th>
                </tr>

                {% for media in media_plan_to_watch %}
                    <tr>
                         <td>{{media.title}}</td>
                         <td>{{media.language}}</td>
                         <td>{{media.rating}}</td>
                         <td>{{media.type_of_media}}</td>
                         <td>{{media.genre}}</td>
                         <td>{{media.review}}</td>
                         <td>{{media.notes}}</td>
                         <td>{{media.date}}</td>
                         <td><a href="">Update</a></td>
                         <td><a href="">Delete</a></td>

                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
        
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h5>COMPLETED</h5>
        <hr>
        <div class="card card-body">
            <table class="table table-sm">
                <tr>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Language</th>
                    <th>Rating</th>
                    <th>Type of Media</th>
                    <th>Genre</th>
                    <th>Review</th>
                    <th>Notes</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Update</th>
                    <th>Remove</th>
                </tr>

                {% for media in media_completed %}
                    <tr>
                         <td>{{media.title}}</td>
                         <td>{{media.language}}</td>
                         <td>{{media.rating}}</td>
                         <td>{{media.type_of_media}}</td>
                         <td>{{media.genre}}</td>
                         <td>{{media.review}}</td>
                         <td>{{media.notes}}</td>
                         <td>{{media.date}}</td>
                         <td><a href="">Update</a></td>
                         <td><a href="">Delete</a></td>

                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
        
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h5>DROPPED</h5>
        <hr>
        <div class="card card-body">
            <table class="table table-sm">
                <tr>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Language</th>
                    <th>Rating</th>
                    <th>Type of Media</th>
                    <th>Genre</th>
                    <th>Review</th>
                    <th>Notes</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Update</th>
                    <th>Remove</th>
                </tr>

                {% for media in media_dropped %}
                    <tr>
                         <td>{{media.title}}</td>
                         <td>{{media.language}}</td>
                         <td>{{media.rating}}</td>
                         <td>{{media.type_of_media}}</td>
                         <td>{{media.genre}}</td>
                         <td>{{media.review}}</td>
                         <td>{{media.notes}}</td>
                         <td>{{media.date}}</td>
                         <td><a href="">Update</a></td>
                         <td><a href="">Delete</a></td>

                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
        
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>





{% endblock %}
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Media(models.Model):
    CATEGORY = (
            ('Movie', 'Movie'),
            ('Tv Show', 'Tv Show'),
            ('Drama', 'Drama'),
            ('Other', 'Other'),
            )
    NUMBER = (
            ('1', '1'),
            ('2', '2'),
            ('3', '3'),
            ('4', '4'),
            ('5', '5'),
            )
    GROUP = (
            ('Action', 'Action'),
            ('Anime', 'Anime'),
            ('Comedy', 'Comedy'),
            ('Crime', 'Crime'),
            ('Fantasy', 'Fantasy'),
            ('Horror', 'Horror'),
            ('Romance', 'Romance'),
            ('Other', 'Other'),
            )
    POSITION = (
            ('Completed', 'Completed'),
            ('Continue Watching', 'Continue Watching'),
            ('Plan to Watch', 'Plan to Watch'),
            ('Dropped', 'Dropped'),
            )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    rating = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=NUMBER, blank=True)
    type_of_media = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=CATEGORY)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=GROUP)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=POSITION)
    review = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home),
    path('products/', views.products),
    path('customer/', views.customer),

    path('media_form/', views.createMedia, name='media_form'),

]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

from .models import *
from .forms import MediaForm

# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    media_continue_watching = Media.objects.filter(status="Continue Watching")
    media_plan_to_watch = Media.objects.filter(status="Plan to Watch")
    media_completed = Media.objects.filter(status="Completed")
    media_dropped = Media.objects.filter(status="Dropped")
    total_continue_watching = Media.objects.filter(status="Continue Watching").count()
    total_plan_to_watch = Media.objects.filter(status="Plan to Watch").count()
    total_completed = Media.objects.filter(status="Completed").count()
    total_dropped = Media.objects.filter(status="Dropped").count()


    context = {'media_continue_watching': media_continue_watching, 'media_plan_to_watch' : media_plan_to_watch , 'media_completed' : media_completed, 'media_dropped': media_dropped,
    'total_continue_watching' : total_continue_watching, 'total_plan_to_watch' : total_plan_to_watch, 'total_completed' : total_completed, 'total_dropped' : total_dropped}

    return render(request, 'accounts/dashboard.html', context)

def products(request):
    return render(request, 'accounts/products.html')

def customer(request):
    return render(request, 'accounts/customer.html')

def createMedia(request):

    form = MediaForm()
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/media_form.html')
```

When add media is pressed it goes to the right url but does not display the form

When add media is pressed it goes to the right url but does not display the formWhen add media is pressed it goes to the right url but does not display the formWhen add media is pressed it goes to the right url but does not display the formWhen add media is pressed it goes to the right url but does not display the form
When add media is pressed it goes to the right url but does not display the formWhen add media is pressed it goes to the right url but does not display the formWhen add media is pressed it goes to the right url but does not display the form

Comment: please pass context on your render

Answer (score 0):

just pass context in your view render

```
def createMedia(request):

    form = MediaForm()
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/media_form.html',context)
```